# How to split a chest weightlifting workout for twice a week

Tags: weightlifting, hypertrophy, chest

I am an advanced beginner in terms of weightlifting but noticed I am not getting enough
development in my chest, particularly my upper chest seems a bit less developed than the rest. Some of this might have to do with shoulder pain I get in my left arm, which kinda limits pressing movements. The pain is due to some weakness in my rotator cuff muscles.

So I was looking to try and split my chest workout to two days a week, but also not overly aggravate my shoulders. I think it can be done, as I have found that lifting with dumbells instead of barbells, and using a neutral grip has really cut down on any discomfort.

So I was not sure the best way to split a workout like this. Does it make more sense to do like the same chest workout twice a week--with 2-3 days of rest in between. Or does it make sense to do pressing movements one day, and then things like flies or dips on other days. I was not sure what has worked for other folks.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.